# AdHoc provisioning profile problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, provisioning, ios-provisioning

With AdHoc provisioning profile I can't start my application on iPhone.
I get this error:
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1096.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 1096.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.

With developer provisioning profile I can start it. Until today it was working. Today I added a new iPhone to the provisioning profile. I heard that I have to recreate totally, but neither this help me. What is the problem? Can you help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this, I had a problem with the provisioning profile. After I restarted my computer it was working. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, in order to use an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, you must “Build and Archive” the app, and install via iTunes.

Comment: I know this, I had a problem with the provisioning profile. After I restarted my computer it was working. Weird.